# Why do \include and \input handle extension name differently?

Tags: input, include

I have a file `bar.tex` that I include in other files.

```
$ cat bar.tex
hello, world
```

```
$ cat foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{bar.tex}
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./foo.aux
(./bar.tex.aux))
No file bar.tex.tex.
(./foo.aux (./bar.tex.aux)) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

You can see above that pdflatex could not include the file because `No
file bar.tex.tex`. It was looking for `bar.tex.tex` instead of
`bar.tex`.

Of course the following works fine.

```
$ cat foo2.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{bar}
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex foo2.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file foo2.aux.
(./bar.tex) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo2.aux
(./bar.aux)) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb>
Output written on foo2.pdf (1 page, 11574 bytes).
```

But when I use `\input` instead of `\include` both `bar.tex` and `bar`
seem to work.

```
$ cat foo3.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{bar.tex}
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex foo3.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo3.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file foo3.aux.
(./bar.tex) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo3.aux)
 )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on foo3.pdf (1 page, 11574 bytes).
Transcript written on foo3.log.
```

```
$ cat foo4.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{bar}
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex foo4.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo4.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file foo4.aux.
(./bar.tex) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo4.aux)
 )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on foo4.pdf (1 page, 11574 bytes).
Transcript written on foo4.log.
```

Why is there this inconsistency between `\include` and `\input`, i.e.
why `\include` requires the file to be included to be speicified without
the extension name whereas `\input` does not care whether or not the
extension name is specified?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. The `\include` command should have an argument that is a file name *without* extension; this is the documented behavior and is a *requirement*.

The command is only meant for inputting `.tex` files in order to do “selective processing” of the material by means of `\includeonly`.

On the other hand, `\input` can be used for *any* kind file (even binaries, if you are bold enough), provided they have an extension, because the default for TeX is to add `.tex` if an extension is missing (except on some implementations).

So the two commands are very different from each other and are not interchangeable. Ultimately, `\include` uses `\input`, but this is not something a user should be concerned with.

Comment: If both `bar` and `bar.tex` exist, then `\input{bar}` inputs `bar.tex`. This makes sense as per your answer because you mentioned that the default for TeX is to add `.tex` if an extension is missing. But when only `bar` exists and `bar.tex` is missing, then `\input{bar}` inputs `bar`. Why? Where can I read about the rules governing these things?

Comment: @LoneLearner It really depends on the implementation. One of them might load `bar` (without extension) if there is no `bar.tex` available (which is what TeX Live does), another might ignore files without extension.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The fact that this behavior is documented doesn't make the inconsistency disappear. And the two commands *are* replaceable in the most frequent use case.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're very wrong, sorry; `\input` doesn't issue a `\clearpage` command, for instance. Have you ever tried `\include{../foo}`? Well, if you do, you'll have a surprise. No problem with `\input{../foo}`, instead. In some restricted cases, the behavior of `\include` and `\input` *seems* to be the same; this is the maximum I can concede.

Comment: There's no bug as everything is documented, but the fact that one of them has a documented requirement that it *should* be without extension, and the other is documented that it can be either with or without extension, is obviously and *by definition* an inconsistency :-) So I don't see why the first sentence is “There is no inconsistency”; at most you can say there is no need or expectation for the two commands to be consistent, because they are so different.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR “the two commands are very different from each other and are not interchangeable”

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's why the inconsistency is not a problem, rather than “there is no inconsistency”. (Or perhaps you're using a different definition of inconsistency that involves some subjective assessment rather than being merely a statement of fact?)

Answer (score 6):

The clue is in the terminal output that you show.

```
(./bar.tex.aux)
```

`\include` needs to construct the name of an `aux` file, and in tex if the user requests `foo` you can not tell if the actual file input is `foo` or `foo.tex` so the most reliable way (if you have reliable users) is to document that the file should always have an extension, and the `\include` argument should not mention the extension.  then `#1.tex` is the document file, and `#1.aux` is the aux file.

Comment: What is different about `\input`? Why does it not to construct the name of the `aux` file?

Comment: @LoneLearner `\input` just inputs the file, no aux file is involved.