# incorporation problem in book class

Tags: include, books

I 'm writing a book and I 'm trying to incorporate the chapters that are in other `tex` files.

I have these chapters:

`ch1.tex`

```
\chapter{1st chapter}

\begin{examp}
example1 example1
\end{examp}

text1 text1
```

`ch2.tex`

```
\chapter{2nd chapter}

\begin{examp}
example2 example2
\end{examp}

text2 text2
```

`ch3.tex`

```
\chapter{3rd chapter}

\begin{examp}
example3 example3
\end{examp}

text3 text3
```

And this is the main file:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examp}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}

main text

\include{ch1.tex}

\include{ch2.tex}

\include{ch3.tex}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that nothing appears when I compile or build the `main.tex`. I also compiled and build *(just for experimentation, I don't know if it was a good idea)* the `ch1.tex`, `ch2.tex` and `ch3.tex`, but nothing yet...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @CarLaTeX , yes they are in the same folder.

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank's for the idea! There was no error indication, but the `log`-file (here https://pastebin.com/6mqjBGca) was writing `No file ch1.tex.tex.`, so I realize that the problem was with `\include{ch1.tex}`, so I change it to `\include{ch1}` and the problem solved!

Comment: Exactly. You'll see this if you look in the log. It says `No file ch1.tex.tex`. `\include` always assumes its argument is a filename without extension

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319506/why-do-include-and-input-handle-extension-name-differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\include{ch1.tex}
```

should be written af

```
\include{ch1}
```

as `\include` always assumes its argument is a file name without extension.

This is also evident from the log file

```
No file ch1.tex.tex.
No file ch2.tex.tex.
No file ch3.tex.tex.
```

Note that `\include` does not throw an error if it cannot find a file.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: I accepted both answers,  because both solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in your main:

```
\input{ch1.tex}
```

instead of `\include{}`

Comment: @Rune thank's a lot!!! Problem solved! Do you know what was the problem with `\include{}`?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας this step should not be necessary, are you 100% sure you are testing with the code you provide above. For example please explain what you mean by `but nothing yet...`

Comment: A final question: What do you recommend as a solution? `\input{ch1.tex}` or `\include{ch1}`?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας, I encountered the problem some time ago, but I have not tried to figure out why it solves it.

Comment: Depends on your needs. `\include` has the advantage that it can be used with `\includeonly` and references to files not listed in `\includonly will still work.