# \input working but \include not showing anything

Tags: input, include

I am facing the following issue. I have a big project on Overleaf that I split into many separate files. All those files are included into the `main.tex` file using the `\input` command. After some time I realised how slowly the project is compiling. I read something about the benefits of using `\include` for including the contents from different files. Mainly it will increase the speed because if the included file is not changed it does not need to be recompiled. Sadly the `\input` command is working but when I change to the `\include` the content is not showing up, but I am also not getting any error message. Maybe someone can help me with this.

```
\input{sections/conclusion.tex}
```

=> this command shows the content of the referenced file

```
\include{sections/conclusion.tex}
```

=> this command does not show the content of the referenced file

Comment: Look in the log file. For include no `.tex ` should be used. So in the log you'll probably find a line saying that it could not find `conclusion.tex.tex`

Comment: and don't use \include for arbitrary parts, it is only meant for whole chapters: it will always start a new page and can't be nested.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super fast and helpful reply. It works now when not specifying the tex extension. For a latex beginner this is so inconsistent to me that you have to specify the text extension for \input and you have to omit it when using \include. Also thanks for telling me only to use it for big parts!

Comment: you don't have to add the extension for \input. Try `\input{sections/conclusion}`.

Comment: thank you very much. That is absolutely right

Comment: potential duplicate: [Why do \include and \input handle extension name differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319506)

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite of the reported issue (`\input{}` was not displaying). Sharing this  still since it is related. Hope this helps someone. My project setup is `main.tex` calls `\input{file1.tex}` then `\input{file2.tex}`. The issue I faced is, the contents upto `file1.tex` was displayed, but the content from `file2.tex` was not displaying.

The reason I found from log is, I had used the following block in the first `file1.tex`

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

After removing the above block from the first input file, `file1.tex`, the content from `file2.tex` started displaying.