# Include fails but input succeeds for the same file?

Tags: pdftex, errors, texlive

### The issue

I'm learning about including multiple files into a latex document to have a more organised flow, and right off the bat I've come across a situation where the `include` command fails where the `input` command succeeds. Shouldn't they both work for the same file?

### Files

File structure

```
.
├── Book
│   └── book.tex
└── Chapters
    └── chapter1.tex
```

Main book file (`book.tex`)

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Book}
\author{First Last}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{../Chapters/chapter1.tex}
% \include{../Chapters/chapter1.tex} fails

The end.

\end{document}
```

Example chapter file (`chapter1.tex`)

```tex
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[10]
```

### Editor and details

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor with the [LatTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extension using [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), `pdflatex` and the `pdfTeX` engine.

When I use `include` instead of `input`, I get the following errors:

```
I can't write on file `../Chapters/chapter1.aux'.
\@include ...mmediate \openout \@partaux "#1.aux"
_______________________________________________________
Emergency stop.
\@include ...mmediate \openout \@partaux "#1.aux"
_______________________________________________________
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on book.log.
Latexmk: Examining 'book.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Comment: \include writes an aux-file and for security reason this will not work if the file is in a parent directory.  (Not related but better leave out the .tex ending).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, moving `book.tex` out of the `Book` directory did the trick, thanks! Also, why is it better to leave out the .tex ending?

Comment: in older system it wouldn't work, it was changed only around two years ago, and so I'm still in the habit. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319509/2388